# OS X Shell Script to run ntpdate

Tags: bash, macos, shell

turns out I'm really bad at shell scripts...

I'm trying to make a script that will run;

```
ntpdate -u time.apple.com
```

So I created this script;

```
#!/bin/sh
ntpdate -u time.apple.com
```

I've chmod +X the script but it won't execute when I call

```
sudo ./timefix.sh

sudo: ./timefix.sh: command not found
```

If I just call ./timefix.sh I get;

```
-bash: ./timefix.sh: Permission denied
```

ntpdate requires sudo privileges to run.

My final goal is to package this up into an app with Automator so that it runs every boot.  I have a handful of Macs in this office that are having internal clock issues. This is meant to be my dirty work around until I can get time to strip them back and replace the RTC batteries.

Can anyone help me fix my script please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change **+X** to a lower case **+x**.

```
chmod +x ./timefix.sh
```